# Infix operator in pattern-matching failure case

Tags: pattern-matching, idris

For some reason, Idris become confused, when infix operator is used inside pattern-matching error handling expression.

```
Right f <- openFile filename Read
      | Left err => printLn err *> pure (_ ** [])


not a terminator, expected: ";", "in", "|", end of input,
function argument | Left err => printLn err *> pure (_ ** []) ^
```

However, it works fine if written in prefix notation.

```
Right f <- openFile filename Read
      | Left err => (*>) (printLn err) (pure (_ ** []))
```

Is it a bug?
What is the reason of parsing failure?

Comment: Looks like it's an instance of [this issue](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/issues/2898).